# what does parameters in murmurhash3 mean?

Tags: c, hash, murmurhash

I am confused with what value should I provide for the `len` parameter in the `MurmurHash3_x86_128()` function (and there are similar functions also). The murmurhash3 code can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/source/browse/branches/chandlerc_dev/MurmurHash3.cpp).

If your answer is that it is the length of the key then please explain the code at line no.154.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is mostly certainly the length of the data to hash in *bytes*, the code at line 154:

```
const int nblocks = len / 16;
```

divides this length into 128bit blocks (or 16 bytes each), this is to promote faster hashing, as `MurmurHash3_x86_128()` processes and mixes 16 bytes (4 x uint32) per iteration.

you'll notice on line 205:

```
switch(len & 15)
```

this catches any trialing bytes, if the size is not a multiple of 16, and the switch cases combine them into the final hash.